# To connect postgres docker with the Widlfy docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, wildfly

I have running widlfy docker and the postgres docker and also nginx docker, I want to connect all the three docker internally so my widlfy can connect to postgres and nginx and I have my url running.  I have added the parameter of networking in the docker-compose.yml file but still not success.
Can you suggest how can I perform this activity of interconnection.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't have all the containers in the same docker-compose.yml, then use the next.

The containers have assigned an internal port and external port, internal is inside the every docker's network and the external is where you can  access using the computer's IP or localhost. In this case you need use your computer's IP, If the IP is 192.168.1.20 and the externals ports for the containers are:

- Widlfy: 8080
- Postgresql: 5432
- ngnx: 80

Then you can connect them using this information:

- Widlfy: 192.168.1.20:8080
- Postgresql: 192.168.1.20:5432
- ngnx: 192.168.1.20:80

The computer's IP use to change in a period of time, it depends of your modem, so check that your IP be the right when you use this option.

Comment: Can you provide any link which I can follow.

Comment: I don't have a link, each one must have a configuration where you put the host and port to connect, for example Widlfy has configuration file where you put the host:port to connect the database.